# How to add specific option to DHCP request of Ubuntu

Tags: networking, dhcp, dhclient

I added the following lines to my `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.cong`

```
option option125 code 125 = string;

option option125 0D:E9:19:01:06:31:32:33:34:35:36:02:0a:31:32:33:34:35:36:37:38:39:61:03:03:61:62:63


request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
    dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers, option125;
```

I checked the wireshark capture and I found that the dhcp client does not send the option 125. What am I missing?

Comment: the typo in the filename is presumably only in your question :) you may want to correct...

Answer (score 1):

`request option125;` means `125` will be included in dhcp-parameter-request-list.

Use `send option125 = 0D:E9:19:01...;` to send optional parameter.

By the way, according to [RFC3925](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3925) your `0D:E9:19:01...` may be `00:00:0D:E9:01...` because enterprise-number is 32bit. If so, you can use built-in `vendor` option for VIVSO:

```
# 3561 is 0x00000de9
option vendor.adslforum code 3561 = string;
# no need to prepend enterprise-number and whole length
send vendor.adslforum = 01:06:31:32:33:34:35:36:02:0a:31:32:33:34:35:36:37:38:39:61:03:03:61:62:63;
```